# how to search inside pdf files on a android device?

Tags: android, search, pdf

I have a full collection of many thousand of pdf files on my Nexus 10, and I really would like to be able to search through them: for example looking for all the pdfs that contains the word "stackoverflow" ;) . Many apps in the markets allow to filter the pdf database by date, title etc, and many of them provide a search function... but for a single pdf only. Do you have any idea ? Many thanks

Comment: Do you only search already existing apps? Or would you also start and implement your own? In the latter case there are a number of Java PDF libraries which you can utilize. Be aware, though, that there are many ways to add text to a PDF but make easy extraction impossible. The solution, therefore, won't ever work 100%.

Comment: thanks mkl ... I only search for existing apps (paid or free I dont care)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to write an app to do this for you then? What you'll need to do is either set the folder to search or recursively search through the file system on your nexus and check for PDF files. You'll then need to use a library like PDFbox to search the text. There's a decent tutorial [here](http://hello-world-2-0.blogspot.co.uk/2008/03/java-library-to-search-in-pdf-files_12.html)

Please note that this will be fairly slow but it is a straightforward solution.

Comment: Dear Chris thank you for your answer but unfortunately i ami just looking for an existing app that would do the job... Do y ou have an idéal?

Comment: Ahhh OK I assumed since you were posting here you wanted to make your own. To the best of my knowledge no such app exists :S

Comment: dammit ! how is that possible ?? :( I am sure a lot of people would accept to pay for an app that does this :)

Comment: You might want to follow [Christian Eric Paran](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1164423/christian-eric-paran) --- looking at his questions here on SO and on the itext-questions mailing list, he seems to work on some Android application which parses PDFs.

Comment: I bump this... is there any news?

Comment: @noobie_on_android i might make this my summer project, if i do i'll let you know

Comment: chris if you are able to do it properly (nice UI, fast search, etc) I think you can get a LOT of money from it

Answer (score 4):

I just found an app that searches within multiple files (I too have hundreds of technical PDFs): [Andro Search](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.chocosoft.as), finally!  I've been looking for years myself.

You could use Evernote, too (some cloud storage providers also have this capability, but it would take me hours to upload all my files and, I don't use them anyway).

There is now a second, possibly better solution: [Librera Reader](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foobnix.pro.pdf.reader).

Librera Reader PRO does not created a huge cache file and is still very fast (relatively speaking).  Look for the search feature in the settings area.